# Determining the Image of a Conformal Mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I'm having some trouble rigorously determining the images of conformal mappings in practice. As Marsden and Hoffman explain in their book *Basic Complex Analysis*, it suffices to analyze boundaries, as shown in the following proposition:

**Proposition.** Let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be two connected regions with boundaries $\partial A$ and $\partial B$. Suppose that $f : A \to f(A)$ is conformal. If $f(A)$ has boundary $\partial B$ and if, for some $z_0 \in A$, we have $f(z_0) \in B$, then $f(A) = B$.

This seems to be a really strong tool for computing the image of a conformal map, but actually verifying that $\partial(f(A)) = \partial B$ doesn't feel that easy.

Say, for example, we have $A = \{z:-\pi/2 < \operatorname{Re}(z) < \pi/2, \operatorname{Im}(z) > 0\}$, $B = \{z : \operatorname{Im}(z) > 0\}$, and $f(z) = \sin{z}$. I'd like to rigorously show that $f(A) = B$ by looking only at boundaries (and one specific point in $A$). How would I do this? While it's true that $f$ extends continuously to a map $\tilde{f}$ on $\bar{A}$, and we can compute $\tilde{f}(\partial A) = \{z : \operatorname{Im}(z) = 0\} = \partial B$, that's not enough to conclude $\partial(f(A)) = \partial(B)$.

In general $\tilde{f}(\partial A) \neq \partial(\tilde{f}(A))$. If $f : A \to \mathbb{C}$ is injective, we do have $\tilde{f}(\partial A) \subset \partial(\tilde{f}(A))$, but this isn't quite enough either, for two reasons. For one, verifying that $f$ is injective involves looking at all points in $A$, which I'm trying to avoid. Second, even knowing that $f$ is injective, we don't have the reverse inclusion.

I feel like I'm missing another tool to streamline this process. How should I approach this?